# Ресурсы для изучения c# под Unity/движка Unity для новичков

Tags: c#, unity3d

Посоветуйте ресурсы/книги для изучения:

1. Шарпа под Unity
2. Самого движка Unity

Желательно хотяб 1 ресурс/книгу на русском :)
Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Если есть желание работать в геймдеве, то про наличие ресурсов (а уж тем более книг) на русском стоит забыть. Да и книги про конкретные технологии слишком быстро устаревают, чтобы их писать, поэтому большая часть информации находится в сети на все том же английском.

Comment: На https://learn.unity.com есть самые базовые курсы в том числе и на русском. Но их одних мало. Еще нужны курсы по C# с изучение патеррнов отдельно, худо-бедно на Youtube что-то есть. Но как только вопрос касается каких-либо фреймворков (например интеграция аналитики или рекламы) вся документация на английском, и даже документация самих Unity не вся на русском.

Answer (score 1):

Очень хорошо начинать с

"Unity в действии. Мультиплатформенная разработка на C#" - Джозеф Хокинг.

А по С#
https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/1.5.php
https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level1/index.php

Answer (score 1):

- Есть отличный тутор от brackeys на англ (и по c# и по unity): [Плейлист Brackeys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j48LtUkZRjU&list=PLPV2KyIb3jR53Jce9hP7G5xC4O9AgnOuL)
- Тутор на русском: [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpKioHg2Buo)
- От code monkey на англ (чисто unity) [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6A4WvsDeLE)
- Ну и сами каналы: Code Monkey, Brackeys, Sykoo, Jason Weimann, Infallible Code - содержат кучу полезной инфы для новичка

Answer (score 0):

Лично я могу посоветовать книгу по C# - это "Программирование для начинающих" Васильев А. Н.

Answer (score -2):

Чтобы изучить сам с# есть книжечка Герберта Шилдта, лично я использовал ее как справочник. Весь материал книги тебе не понадобится, но в разработке полезная штука если что то забыл

Ссылка: https://yadi.sk/i/et-juXAuvXLiAQ